# WPF: Why isn't the NameScope attached property inherited?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

It seems to me that the [NameScope.NameScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.namescope(v=vs.110).aspx) attached property is an ideal candidate to have `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` set so that it is inherited by children. Why isn't this the case?

That would certainly make it much easier for the programmer to get the effective `NameScope` of a particular object, and would even allow something like

```
<Element NameScope.NameScope="{Binding Path=Target.(NameScope.NameScope), ...}" ... />
```

to be used in Xaml to mirror the `NameScope` of another object. Although I think this makes the code a bit more difficult to follow, it would have uses for things that are often detached from the visual tree, like `ContextMenu`.

Is it possibly because the attached property was meant to be generic (non-`FrameworkElement` bound)? In the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/NameScope.cs,152) there is no `PropertyMetadata` registered at all for the attached property.

Comment: Property metadata of the NameScope property is of type PropertyMetadata, not FrameworkPropertyMetadata, hence there aren't any FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions. Besides that, the Remarks in the documentation say that "*the attached property usage is primarily to facilitate attaching XAML namescopes to objects that do not share inheritance for XAML namescope implementations. DependencyObject and derived classes support this inheritance natively*".

Comment: But I believe the metadata is of type `PropertyMetadata` only because the property metadata is omitted in the dependency property constructor, as per the source. I read those remarks, but the part about _"... support this inheritance natively"_ is misleading, because they don't actually inherit the attached property, but rather have functions to facilitate searching up the visual tree to get the NameScope.